# Oracle database 10g express

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I've just installed Oracle 10g Express on my home computer but when I try to go to the database Home Page,

I get this error:

> This site is inaccessible 127.0.0.1 does not allow the connection

I'm using Windows 10.

I've run `lsnrctl status` and here is the lsnrctl  output:

```
 LSNRCTL for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 11-NOV. -2017 17:57:18

 Copyright (c) 1991, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Connexion Ó (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
 STATUT du PROCESSUS D'ECOUTE
 ------------------------
 Alias                     LISTENER
 Version                   TNSLSNR for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
 Date de dÚpart                       11-NOV. -2017 16:03:51
 DurÚe d'activitÚ                    0 jours 2 heures 1 min. 52 sec
 Niveau de trace           off
 SÚcuritÚ                  ON: Local OS Authentication
 SNMP                      OFF
 Fichier de paramÞtres du processus d'Úcoute     C:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
 Fichier journal du processus d'Úcoute             C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\network\log\listener.log
 RÚcapitulatif d'Úcoute des points d'extrÚmitÚ...
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
 RÚcapitulatif services...
 Le service "CLRExtProc" comporte 1 instance(s).
   L'instance "CLRExtProc", statut UNKNOWN, comporte 1 gestionnaire(s) pour ce service...
 Le service "orcl" comporte 1 instance(s).
   L'instance "orcl", statut READY, comporte 1 gestionnaire(s) pour ce service...
 Le service "orclXDB" comporte 1 instance(s).
   L'instance "orcl", statut READY, comporte 1 gestionnaire(s) pour ce service...
 La commande a rÚussi
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong here?

Comment: if you're trying to get to em express webpage to manage your db, it's not on port 80

Comment: ps there's a newer version of XE available, but here's how to find your port http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/manageability/emx-intro-1965965.html#A2

Comment: XE 10g is over a decade old. Why not try visiting the Oracle website in real time rather than throw the Wayback machine ;)